# Events not working when using Mustache with Backbone.js

Tags: events, view, backbone.js, mustache

So I am making a test app using RequireJs, Mustache and Backbone.js. I had some success with rendering the collection of models with the Mustache template. But my Mustache template has a button and when I try to bind click event on the button in the view, the button click doesn't invoke the callback function. I am really stuck, can someone tell me where I am not doing right?

Here is my code:

ItemView.js:

```
define(['jquery', 'backbone', 'underscore', 'mustache', '../../atm/model/item'], function ($, Backbone, _, Mustache, Item) {

var ItemView = Backbone.View.extend({        
    initialize: function() {
    },

    tagName: 'li',

    events: {
        'click .button': 'showPriceChange'
    },

    render: function() {
        var template = $('#template-atm').html();
        var itemObj = this.model.toJSON();
        itemObj['cid'] = this.model.cid;

        var rendering = Mustache.to_html(template, itemObj);
        this.el = rendering;

        return this;
    },

    showPriceChange: function(event) {
        alert('Changing...');
        $('#' + elemId).empty();
        $('#' + elemId).append(document.createTextNode('Changed'));
    },       
});

return ItemView;
});
```

atm.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Elevator</title>
    <script data-main="scripts/main" src="scripts/require-jquery.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">

    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Vending Machine</h1>
    <div id="atm-items">
    </div>

    <script id="template-atm" type="html/template">
        <li>
            <p>Item: {{name}}</p>
            <label for="price-{{cid}}">Price:</label>
            <input id="price-{{cid}}" type="text" value="{{price}}"/>
            <button class="button">Change</button>
            <p id="status-{{name}}-{{cid}}">- -</p>
        </li>
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i think it does a post/submit when you click the button. It is the default for the button. Try adding `type="button"` for it and tell me what happens.

Comment: No go :-( I changed the button element to <input type="button" class="button" value="Change"></input>, but still no events

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're replacing the view's `el` inside `render`:

```
render: function() {
    //...
    this.el = rendering;
    //...
}
```

When you do that, you're losing the jQuery [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) that is attached to `this.el`, that `delegate` handler (which Backbone adds) is responsible for the event routing.

Usually, you *add* things to `this.el` rather than *replacing* `this.el`. If your template looked like this:

```
<script id="template-atm" type="html/template">
     <p>Item: {{name}}</p>
     <label for="price-{{cid}}">Price:</label>
     <input id="price-{{cid}}" type="text" value="{{price}}"/>
     <button class="button">Change</button>
     <p id="status-{{name}}-{{cid}}">- -</p>
 </script>
```

then you would `this.$el.append(rendering)` in your view's `render`; this would give you an `<li>` in `this.el` since you've set your view's `tagName` to `li`.

Alternatively, if you really need to keep the `<li>` in the template, you could use [`setElement`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-setElement) to replace `this.el`, `this.$el`, and take care of the event delegation:

```
this.setElement(rendering);
```

Presumably you're wrapping all these `<li>`s in a [`<ul>`, `<ol>`, or `<menu>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/li.html) somewhere else; if you're not then you're producing invalid HTML and the browser might try to correct it for you, the corrections might cause you trouble elsewhere as your HTML structure might not be what your selectors think it is.

Comment: Spot on, after using setElement, the event is triggered correctly. I guess the documentation is a bit confusing on el and setElement. Thanks !!